# Add URL field to footcites using style=authortitle-icomp

Tags: biblatex, biber

I would like to add the field URL for footcited @online{} items. The biblatex manual was not helpful for me. I use biber and biblatex with the following options:

```
\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-icomp,
    sortlocale=de DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=true, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=true
]{biblatex}
```

I know that the URL is printed if I select e.g.

```
style=verbose-ibid
```

, but I definitely want to stick to

```
style=authortitle-icomp
```

I would accept a solution if it would mean that the URL field is printed for each source, because I only have URLs in my cited websources.

Here is a minimal working example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{report}

\listfiles
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{some_article,
  author = {Nachname1, Vorname1},
  title = {Titel1},
  journaltitle = {Zeitschrift},
  date = {2006},
  volume = {6},
  pages = {19--75}
}
@online{some_website,
  author = {Nachname2, Vorname2},
  title = {Titel2},
  year = 2014,
  url = {example.com/index.html},
  urldate = {2012-26-11}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authortitle-icomp,
    %style=verbose-ibid,
    sortlocale=de DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=true, 
    doi=false,
    eprint=true
]{biblatex}

\bibliography{\jobname}

\begin{document}

some text here \footcite{some_article}, some text there \footcite{some_website}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using `style=verbose-ibid` prints the URL but puts also a lot of information that I don't want. Note that I also want to stick to the document class report (using, e.g., document class article prints the URL in that scenario).

However, from [this Link (sorry it is in german)](http://www.golatex.de/biblatex-zitierstil-fussnote-anpassung-authortitle-t5707.html) I tried to build a solution:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{
  \iffieldundef{shorthand}{
    \ifnameundef{labelname}{}{
      \printnames{labelname}
      \setunit{\nametitledelim}
    }
    \usebibmacro{cite:title}
    \iffieldundef{url}{}{
      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}
      \printfield{url}
    }
  }
  {\usebibmacro{cite:shorthand}}
}
```

It prints the URL but messes up the automatic abbreviations "i.b." (in german "Ebd.") for repeated citiations, i.e., all citations are then explicitly printed.

Comment: The verbose styles are intended for cases where you do not have a separate bibliography. If you want full citations in the footnotes, then you need a style of that kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After studying the style file`authortitle-icomp.cbx`in more detail, I came up with a solution by redefining the bibmacro`cite:title`.

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}
  \iffieldundef{url}{}{\nametitledelim\printfield{url}}}}
```

The redefined bibmacro checks (for any source) if the field `url` is defined, if so it appends a comma followed by the value of field `url`. I placed the code at the preamble of my latex document.

Comment: This works for other fields as well, just swap out url