# Show "notes" field in footnotes for footcite with citestyle=verbose

Tags: biblatex

Is there a way to force the "notes" field to show in footnote citations?  I know you can suppress fields with:

```
\AtEveryCiteKey{\clearfield{url}}
```

for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did the trick in the preamble:

```
\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}
  \iffieldundef{notes}{}{\nametitledelim\printfield{notes}}}}
```

See also this question: [Add URL field to footcites using style=authortitle-icomp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220269/add-url-field-to-footcites-using-style-authortitle-icomp/223736#comment587279_223736)