# add URL to citation apa biblatex

Tags: biblatex, citing, urls, apa-style

I need to add the URL in the citations in footnotes for every source that has a URL. It should look like the footnotes *a* and *b* in the MWE output. I found this: [Add URL field to footcites using style=authortitle-icomp](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220269/add-url-field-to-footcites-using-style-authortitle-icomp) but the accepted solution doesn't work for me and I'm not able to modify it to make it work properly (I have commented it in the MWE).

I'm using biblatex, biber, APA style, italian. I edit on Sharelatex.com.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}         
\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-apa}

\defbibfilter{online}{
    type=online
}

\defbibfilter{offline}{
    type=book or
    type=article or
    type=report
}

%\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
%\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}
%\iffieldundef{url}{}{\nametitledelim\printfield{url}}}}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@online{cit1,
  title = {Title},
  url = {http://www.website.com},
  timestamp = {2013-04-11T17:20:44Z},
  titleaddon = {Example},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@report{cit2,
  author = {BBBAuthor, Name},
  title = {Title Title Title},
  url = {http://www.example.com},
  timestamp = {2013-04-11T17:20:44Z},
  titleaddon = {Website Name},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@book{cit3,
  location = {Location},
  title = {Title Title},
  timestamp = {2016-02-01T21:50:03Z},
  langid = {english},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  author = {Author, Name},
  date = {2001}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

Bla bla\footnote{\cite[]{cit1}, \url{http://www.website.com}}.
Bla\footnote{\cite[]{cit2}, \url{http://www.example.com}}.
BLA BLA\footcite[]{cit1}
Blaaa blaa bla\footcite[]{cit3}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,filter=offline,title={Bibliography}] 
\printbibliography[title={Online},filter=online,heading=subbibliography]

\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we need to modify the citation commands, the solution depends on the style quite a lot and `biblatex-apa`'s cite macros differ from the standard ones in `authortitle` quite a bit, this is why your attempt didn't work.

It is probably easiest to modify the `cite` macro directly here (one could change `cite:plabelyear+extrayear` but that could interfere with other commands)

```
\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Multiple cites in one command
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
% Single cite
   {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
% No author/editor
     {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
       \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
% Normal cite
     {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
        {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
          {\printnames{shortauthor}}
          {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<-- this is new
   \printfield[citeurl]{url}%<--- and so is this
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother
```

is a copy of the definition from `apa.cbx` with two lines added in towards the end.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[babel]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=apa,backend=biber]{biblatex}         
\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{italian-apa}

%\renewbibmacro*{cite:title}{%
%\printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield[citetitle]{labeltitle}
%\iffieldundef{url}{}{\nametitledelim\printfield{url}}}}

\makeatletter
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
  \iffieldequals{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}
% Multiple cites in one command
   {\setunit{\compcitedelim}%
    \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}}%
% Single cite
   {\ifthenelse{\ifnameundef{labelname}\OR\iffieldequalstr{entrytype}{patent}}
% No author/editor
     {\usebibmacro{cite:noname}%
       \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
       \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
       \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}
% Normal cite
     {\ifnameundef{shortauthor}
        {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{labelname}}%
        {\cbx@apa@ifnamesaved
          {\printnames{shortauthor}}
          {\printnames[labelname][-\value{listtotal}]{author}\addspace\printnames[sabrackets]{shortauthor}}}%
      \setunit{\nameyeardelim}%
      \usebibmacro{cite:plabelyear+extrayear}%
      \savefield{namehash}{\cbx@lasthash}}}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\space}%<-- this is new
   \printfield[citeurl]{url}%<--- and so is this
   \setunit{\multicitedelim}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{cit1,
  title = {Title},
  url = {http://www.website.com},
  titleaddon = {Example},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@report{cit2,
  author = {BBBAuthor, Name},
  title = {Title Title Title},
  url = {http://www.example.com},
  titleaddon = {Website Name},
  urldate = {2013-04-10},
  date = {2004}
}

@book{cit3,
  location = {Location},
  title = {Title Title},
  langid = {english},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  author = {Author, Name},
  date = {2001}
}

\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
Bla bla\footcite[]{cit1}.
Bla\footcite[]{cit2}
BLA BLA\footcite[]{cit1}
Blaaa blaa bla\footcite[]{cit3}.

\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc,nottype=online,title={Bibliography}] 
\printbibliography[title={Online},type=online,heading=subbibliography]
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

Comment: Note that in the MWE I could do away with the bibfilters and use `type=online` and `nottype=online` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! And thanks for the comment about the filters, I will try that as well.

Comment: @CarCaSSa Glad to be of help. You will see a difference between the bibfilters and the `type`/`nottype` thingy once you start citing say `@collection`s or `@inbook` works.